# First redraw by search datatables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, datatables

Hi everybody and first sorry for my English. My problem is I have a table (jquery datatable) and loaded with the data correctly. I associated with that table have a google map with markers, and operation sought is that when you click on a marker map the corresponding infobox (this works) to open and edit an image in the table (this is the problem). When it is the other way around, from the table we click, it works perfect (open the infobox and modifies the image). The strange thing is that when I first "redraw" in the table (eg I seek some element), and I click on the map marker, and it works: -S Is there an event I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is really impossible to say without a code example that demonstrates your setup. Maybe you miss some obvious benefits from an event or callback, but hard to tell without seeing what you actually is doing at the moment.

Comment: `var table = $('#datatable_runners').DataTable( {
         "scrollY":        '50vh',
         "scrollCollapse": true,
         //responsive: true,
         "initComplete": function() {
          console.log("carga completa");
          },
      });
      
    table.draw();`

Comment: This is my initialize. All fields are just defined on runtime (all tr with two columns, nothiung special)

Answer (score 0):

I find the error, only a library of DataTables (scroller) bad referenced. I don't need it, so I delete it and works. Sorry for the inconvenients.